# how to draw high chart using function?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, charts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
        $('#div-chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Purchase',
                align: 'center'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ' '
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: <?php echo json_encode($result['day']) ?>,
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Amount (Millions)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Purchase',
                data: <?php echo json_encode($result['amount']) ?>
            }]
      });
});
```

In  `$(document).ready(function(){});` I'm defining the properties how my chart is drawn, what comes to x-axis and y-axis and properties of it. But, now I want to build a function in which I pass argument whether I want to draw high chart or canvas and then that function draw chart. How to start this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Write a common function and replace the all hard coded values with params. I am not sure where you stuck.

Comment: I am totally new with it. How to start with that function. can you give ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//dummy data    
$result['day'] = array('Sun', 'Man', 'Tue', 'Wed');
$result['amount'] = array(1, 32, 324, 3531, 15, 6);
$result['chartType'] = 'canvas';
//$result['chartType'] = 'normal'; //this one to draw normal chart
?>canvas

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.0.4/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/4.0.4/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #div-chart {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    DrawhighChart(); //first draw high chart by default and make it hidden by
    <?php if($result['chartType'] === 'canvas'){
        ?> DrawCanvas($('#div-chart').highcharts());
    <?php } else { ?> $('#div-chart').show(); <?php } ?>
});

function DrawCanvas(chart) {
    EXPORT_WIDTH = 1000;
    var render_width = EXPORT_WIDTH;
    var render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth

    // Get the cart's SVG code
    var svg = chart.getSVG({
        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
            sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
        }
    });

    // Create a canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = render_height;
    canvas.width = render_width;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Create an image and draw the SVG onto the canvas
    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, render_width, render_height);
    };
    image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svg);
}


function  DrawhighChart(){
    Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
    $('#div-chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Purchase',
            align: 'center'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: <?php echo json_encode($result['day']) ?>,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Amount (Millions)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Purchase',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($result['amount']) ?>
        }]
    });
}

</script>

<div id='div-chart' style="display: none"></div>
```

Note:
If you want to change the properties dynamically follow the same thing you did for x-axis values for example if you want to change the title then

```
 title: {
            text: '<?php echo $result["title"] ?>',
            align: 'center'
        },
```

Comment: Can you explain this code with simple example?  What type of argument this take and how it draw chart.

Comment: Args depends on your needs. So you want to convert draw the same high chart to canvas?

Comment: Here is conversion of highchart to canvs http://jsfiddle.net/willkoehler/1p81fbzs/

Comment: yes i want to draw same high chart into canvas and i want a general function. The code given above is just a sample data. I take data dynamically and then want to render it in chart.

Comment: Thank You so much, if i have problem, i will comment. Thank You Again :)

Comment: Hope that will work. Thanks for upvoting and Happy coding.

Comment: Hii, In draw high chart function you are using the properties of high chart. what i want is to use this property in dynamically in a variable and by using that variable we render chart. That same variable is used to draw canvas chart, not different properties we write in canvas function. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: The properties are same in both charts. you need to dynamically bring that from the PHP `$result`

Comment: I have not used any different properties on for canvas, just convert high-chart to the canvas, so nothing changes there. run the above code in a separate PHP file. then you can understand.

Comment: I already run. yes i got data from $result, but what i am trying to say that here we give statically the title, axis name etc. all the properties. I want this is set dynamically like title, subtitle based on data we fetch.

Comment: Oh, Dude its same as you are passing the value to x-axis. check i have updated the answer.

Comment: Wherever you want to change the data dynamically just echo using PHP codes

Comment: I don't want to use php. I want to use ajax

Comment: Hope you are getting ajax responses now create functions like previous answer(see andy's answer) now pass the data to that function, now just change hard code data to js var.

Comment: Ask seperated question for that issue

Comment: I ask can you look at that and give me answer?

Comment: I will, If i can.

Comment: how to render chart based on different id? This is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the official [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart). You have to call `Highcharts.chart('div-chart', { ... your settings ... }`. You can assign this to a variable, but not to your div like you did above. And what do you mean with draw canvas OR Highchart?

Comment: Draw Canvas and High Chart, we have two methods to draw a chart first we can use high chart and other we can use canvas to draw a chart. Now i want a common function in which we pass argument like we want to build high chart or canvas. The Properties of these chart is also want access through variable.

Comment: `function draw(method) { if (method == "highchart") { ... } else { ... }

draw("highchart"); or draw("canvas");

Answer (score 0):

I think what Thamaraiselvam ment was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawChart(chart_type, args...);
});

function drawChart(chart_type, args....){
    if (type === 'highchart') {
        drawHighChart(args);
    } else if (type === 'canvas'){
        drawCanvas(args);
    }
}

function drawHighChart(args){

}

function drawCanvas(args){

}
```

Not directly related but still. I suggest you to look on the side of Jquery which gives the possibility to produce a lot of fancy graphic output with usually less effort than with javascript. see [this](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/) documentation. Greetings andy